# Assign to a Javascript variable the member's database id

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

On my webpage, when the user logs in, he stays on the same page:

```
echo '<form action="" method="POST" class="Form">';
```

I want to keep the database id of the user in a Javascript variable:

```
if (Session::isLoggedIn())
{
    echo '<script>';
    echo '  let memberId = "' . (string)($_SESSION['memberId']) . '";';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Unfortunately, when the user logs in, my `let memberId = "' . (string)($_SESSION['memberId']) . '";` doesn't appear in the client side source code (the page doesn't seem to be as reloaded as I expected).

So what can I do to keep the database id of the user in a Javascript variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of your code appears, then Session::isLoggedIn() is not true when you user has logged in.
Then, are you sure that $_SESSION['memberId'] contains the id_user when he is logged in?
I would also find it more clear, if you pass the id otherwise, first to html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="memberId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['memberId'] ?>"
```

and then in JS

```
let memberId = document.getElementsByName("memberId")[0].value;
```

Comment: My mistake, my `Session::isLoggedIn()` test wasn't in the right place. Thanks (and sorry)